# How can you upload an image from within a settings page?

Tags: images, uploads, options, open-graph

Is there an easy way to include an upload box to your settings page?

I am building an Open Graph options page and I like users to upload a standard image directly from that page.

Comment: This was more what I wanted: http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/ Now to figure out how you can detect if a certain image has been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress provides a convenient function for just this purpose: [`wp_handle_upload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload).

Assuming that you already have the appropriate file form field in your settings page, and that you're using `register_setting()` for your options, and therefore already have an options validation callback, simply handle the file form field data using `wp_handle_upload()`. Here's an example:

```
<?php
// Validate file fields
else if ( 'file' == $optiondetails['type'] ) {
    if ( isset( $input[$setting] ) ) {
        // Only update setting if input value is in the list of valid options
        $setting_file = $setting . '_file';
        $valid_input[$setting] = ( isset( $_FILES[$setting_file] ) ? theme-slug_image_upload( $setting, $input ) : $valid_input[$setting] );
    }
}
?>
```

Then, you just need to define that `theme-slug_image_upload()` callback, using `wp_handle_upload()`:

```
<?php
function theme-slug_image_upload( $the_file, $input ) {
    $data = $_FILES[$the_file . '_file'];
    if ( '' != $data['name'] )
        $upload = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES[$the_file . '_file'], array( 'test_form' => false ) );
    else
        $upload['url'] = $input[$the_file];
    return $upload['url'];
}
?>
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: It would be so nice with a full example of the validation callback functions. I can't seem to make it work.