# upload script in plugin development

Tags: plugin-development, uploads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you upload an image from within a settings page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41634/how-can-you-upload-an-image-from-within-a-settings-page)

I am developing a plugin. Which has a form.

The form contains the following fields.

1. Course Name
2. Course file.

The course file field is of type file from where I will upload a file. The name of the file I will store in database and the the uploaded file should save in the wp-content/uploads directory.

How will I do this in wordpress. I am new to plugin development so please help me out.

Comment: Please [search the site for related questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=file+upload+plugin) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [wp_upload_bits](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits), it will create th file in the upload folder.

Example :

```
 $upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES["course_file"]["name"], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES["course_file"]["tmp_name"] ) );
```